# How to remove Pay later from Paypal Authorize page

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We are trying to integrate paypal checkout into our web app. I can hide the pay later ( credit) and the card option from showing up easily using the query parameter disable-funding=credit,card as indicated [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/#disable-funding)  However I still see the options for Pay-later on my Paypal authorize page (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes...) (screenshot attached ). How can I disable them from showing up on the authorize page? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You only control the buttons displayed on your own site.

Once on a PayPal page, the buyer can always use any funding source they might be eligible for. It's between them and PayPal, and it's all kept private by design.

(The receiver of a PayPal payment won't ever know whether the payer used one of the above funding sources, or something else like a bank or card or PayPal balance. It's none of their business.)

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the option disableFunding to  'credit'.

If you are using a script tag

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=YOUR_ID&disable-funding=credit"></script>
```

If a package set the prop  named disableFunding of options in to credit .

eg. Using react

```
<PayPalButton
  amount="1.00"
  currency={currency}
  catchError={(err: Error) => console.log(err)}
  options={{ currency:"USD", clientId:"xxxxx", disableFunding: 'credit' }}        
  onError={(err: Error) => console.log(err)}
/>
```

Comment: This controls the display of a Pay Later or PayPal Credit button on your own site -- but it does NOT change what will be available once the buyer reaches a PayPal checkout page, as in this question's screenshot.

Comment: `'disable-funding': 'credit'`(written as if it was a url parameter) worked for me!

Comment: not working to me, when press `orange paypal` button it's still show `paylater` on the dialog @RilDev

Answer (score 0):

If the funding sources are none of our business, what is the purpose of 'disable-funding' parameter ?

I agree with you that if we get the money, we don't care how the customer made the payment, but I'm in a situation where I allow payments in installments only for orders amounts greater than $xxx.

It works great with Stripe (which let me enable/disable sources as I wish) but if I want to add Paypal to my app, this "Pay in 4 installments" messes up with everything.

The only solution I have now is to allow Paypal payments only for orders > $xxx.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).